# i want to change my jQuery script to angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This is my code and it working fine, I want to same in angular

css is here

```
.hide{
display: none;
  }
ul.menu-list li a.selected{
background-color: dimgrey;
}
```

HTML is here

```
<ul class="menu-list">
<li><a id="menu-add-category" class="selected">Add Category</a></li>
<li><a id="menu-add-type" class="deselected">Add Type</a></li>
</ul>
       <div id="add-category" class="show form">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <label>Add Category :</label>
                <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="category"/>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="add-type" class="hide">
            <form method="post" action="">
            <label>Category :</label>
            <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="category"/>
            <label>Types :</label>
            <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="type"/><br><br>
            </form>
        </div>
```

jQuery is here

```
 <script>
 $('#menu-add-category') .on('click', function () {
    $('#add-category').removeClass('hide');
    $('#add-category').addClass('show');
    $('#add-type').removeClass('show');
    $('#add-type').addClass('hide');
    $(this).removeClass('deselected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#menu-add-type').removeClass('selected');
    $('#menu-add-type').addClass('deselected');
    });

 $('#menu-add-type') .on('click', function () {
    $('#add-type').removeClass('hide');
    $('#add-type').addClass('show');
    $('#add-category').removeClass('show');
    $('#add-category').addClass('hide');
    $(this).removeClass('deselected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#menu-add-category').removeClass('selected');
    $('#menu-add-category').addClass('deselected');
  });
 </script>
```

I was written code in jQuery can u please help me to do same using angular. actually, i want to know how to use toggle-class for two classes

Comment: If you want to toggle css classes based on a expression i.e. some value being true or false. You need to take a look at ng-class

Comment: the `ng-click` and `ng-class` directives will help you

Comment: jQuery is library that provides you functions to use. On the other hand, Angular is a framework, you will have to rewrite the entire project you're doing from scratch in Angular.

Comment: I tried to do, with angular but I was not getting any idea how to do, can anyone  explain me with small example, please